# PowerApps/Dataverse/Model-driven App/Microsoft Project. Is there any chance to change format of that date?

Tags: powerapps, dataverse, model-driven, project-online, model-driven-app

I've an issue with my Model-driven, PowerApps App.
Actually in the Dataverse table data-fields are formated that way:

[Dataverse data field format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRz99.png)

Is there any way to change it to:
"DD/MM/YYYY” or "DD.MM.YY" format?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the legacy Admin area, if you go to the "Advanced Settings" area, navigate to "Settings" | "Administration" | "System Settings" | "Formats", you will get lots of options of pre-defined formatting based on your locality.  Furthermore, you can hit the "Customize" button to further specify what you need.  In your case, the customize button will have a "Date" tab that you can use.
The last time I checked, this was not yet implemented in the Power Platform Admin Center (PPAC), but the PPAC is getting new features regularly, so it may get added sometime soon.